# How to do a mail merge with attachments

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-word, attachments, mail-merge

I'm trying to use MS Word and Outlook 2003 to send a bunch of emails with attachments but apparently this option is not allowed.

¿Any clean way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an article that is on point for you: [Mail Merge to E-mail with Attachments](http://word.mvps.org/FAQs/MailMerge/MergeWithAttachments.htm) ...

> This procedure can be used to mail
>   merge to e-mail, including attachments
>   with each message when Microsoft
>   Office Outlook is installed. It has
>   been used with all versions of Office
>   from Office 97 up to and including
>   Office 2007.